# Javascript UndoManager Browser Support

Tags: javascript, html, wysiwyg, undo

The HTML5 spec mentions an UndoManager that can be used to query the previous state of a document that's been edited by a user ( http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#undomanager ). Do any browsers support this? Is there any hope of browsers ever supporting it?

Comment: It was '[removed] from the W3C version since it's not mature enough to be called [Last Call]' http://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=11021

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can test your own browsers by navigating them to [HTML5Test.com](http://html5test.com/). You can also [test for it](http://diveintohtml5.info/everything.html) on your page (and then use it if it exists) by doing the following:

```
return typeof UndoManager !== 'undefined';
```

The browsers that currently support it are limited.

No Support: Chrome 6.0, IE 8, FF 3.6

```
Browser       Score (160)   UndoManager Support
--------------------------------------
IE8           19            no
FF3.6         101           no
Chrome 6      142           no
Safari 4.0.5  70            no
Opera 10.53   102           no
```

Chrome, Firefox, and Opera score well on overall HTML5 support. So, UndoManager support may be coming soon. Safari has promised full HTML5 support "soon", as well. IE9 is supposed to be more focused on web standards.

So, it doesn't look right at this moment, but I imagine there will be 3-4 major browsers with support in the near future.

Comment: I just ran the results and out of 160 points this is how the latest version of the browsers did.  Chrome 116, Opera 102, Firefox 101, Safari 70, and IE8 19.  If I was a betting man I would follow Chrome and watch for them to have functionality for Undo Manager first.  Who knows though.

Comment: If it will be supported in Chrome, it will be aviable for every webkit browser, like Safari.

Comment: @Bakaburg Not true anymore, because Google forked WebKit today.

Comment: Firefox has UndoManager from version 20, although [it's disabled by default](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15888611/undomanager-support-in-firefox).

Comment: Sad that this is still not widely supported in 2021. For reference, it looks like there are [ongoing W3C discussions about the API spec](https://www.w3.org/2019/09/18-undomanager-minutes.html), and there's also [this thread on GitHub](https://github.com/w3c/editing/issues/150). WebKit had an early implementation that was [removed in 2012](http://trac.webkit.org/changeset/133326/webkit).