# UndoManager support in Firefox

Tags: html, firefox, undo-redo

I'm a little confused about how to use undoManager in Firefox.  According to [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Firefox_20_for_developers), Firefox 20 now has support for it, but I can't figure out where. I've checked under `document`, `Objects`, etc., but can't find it anywhere.  I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, so can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to set the "dom.undo_manager.enabled" preference to use it, so far, since the spec is still in flux.

Comment: Thank you very much!  But I had to add the preference manually, so I'm wondering why it wasn't just included and set to disabled by default.  Anyway, I'll have to look into this feature more because I also thought undoManager would access the current undo stack, which it doesn't seem to be doing...

Comment: Does it actually work? I made a simple document with an input, textarea and contenteditable div, and each always has a null `undoManager` property and `document.undoManager.length` is always 0.

Comment: `document.undoManager` should work at least for some things, since there are automated tests that it does...  See http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/content/html/content/test/test_undoManager.html