# textarea: button to trigger native undo/redo

Tags: javascript

I have a textarea. It has default undo/redo functionality, either with ctrl-z/y or by right-clicking and choosing copy/paste.

I want to create an undo/redo button and trigger the native undo/redo. I'm not sure how to trigger this. (Was surprised that my users don't know ctrl-z)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to get document.execCommand('undo') working in the same manner across browsers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16225718/unable-to-get-document-execcommandundo-working-in-the-same-manner-across-bro)

Comment: That question contains the answer to my question (use execCommand). But finding that question requires already knowing to search for "execCommand", which is what I didn't know. So I still think it could be worthwhile to have this question here with an answer. But whatever others think...

Comment: **possible** duplicate, does not mean it **is** a duplicate per se, it's just a flag for moderators to take a look, and for future people landing here to have an extra link to check out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `document.execCommand` to achieve this functionallity. It is used by some HTML-editors.

[execCommand compatibility](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/execCommand.html)

And by now, this is [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand), and **should not** be used.

Comment: ["This feature is **obsolete**"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand)

Comment: Indeed it is now. :) But back in 2013 to late 2017 it wasn't.

Answer (score 0):

You can create functions to trigger undo and redo functionality on button click.

Undo button functionality as follows:

```js
const handleUndoButtonClick = () => {
  document.execCommand('undo', false, '');
};
```

Redo button functionality as follows:

```js
const handleRedoButtonClick = () => {
  document.execCommand('redo', false, '');
};
```

Call `handleUndoButtonClick()` on undo button click and call `handleRedoButtonClick()` on redo button click.