# Assign Ctrl +Z to Escape Key

Tags: jquery

i have a function and i would like on keyup Escape (27) undo the previous event.
If I press ctrl+z this is working but I would like to assig the control Z to the Escape key

```
$('.toAct').not('.id').on('keyup', function(e) {
 if (e.which === 27) {
  e.preventDefault()

   // CTRL Z FUNCTION
   //$(this).click('ctrl+z')

  } 
})
```

Comment: You can't trigger an 'undo' operation in the manner you're attempting. It depends on specifically what logic was performed as to how you undo it. The standard browser-level undo operation would be invoked by using `execCommand()` but browser support may patchy.

Comment: You probably want to implement your own undo stack.

Comment: yes that's right. this is in a table td I have contenteditable on and on escape keyup i would like to undo text input and go back again to the original text

Comment: Possible duplicate of [textarea: button to trigger native undo/redo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18054623/textarea-button-to-trigger-native-undo-redo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Document#executeCommand`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand) to perform `undo` action.

```js
$('.toAct').not('.id').on('keyup', function(e) {
  if (e.which === 27) {
    e.preventDefault()
    document.execCommand('undo', false, null);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class="toAct"></textarea>
```

[MDN docs for available commands.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand#Commands)