# Undo for div tag

Tags: javascript, html

I have `div` tag with `contentEditable = 'true'`. When I enter text from my keyboard and then call the `undo` function (`document.execCommand('undo',false, null)`), all of the text I entered is deleted. I want to just undo the last character typed. How can I do that?

```js
function doUNDO() 
{
    document.execCommand('undo',false, null);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="formulas.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    </head>
    <body id="main" spellcheck="false"> 
        <span contenteditable="false">
            <button onclick="doUNDO()">UNDO</button>
        </span> 

        <div id = "mainDiv"contenteditable="true">a</div>  
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is an uncommon pattern. Usually 'undo' refers to a segment of typing - and not 1 character. The delete key is already there when a keyboard is available. Usually 'back' is for removing the last character.

Comment: A little more explanation might be in order. Is someone writing an essay in this div - or something long that they traverse and edit in many places?

Comment: What if I delete a word, and then I want to undo that action?

Comment: This seems to be what you're looking for. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16225718/unable-to-get-document-execcommandundo-working-in-the-same-manner-across-bro

Comment: @sheriffderek: No, that's about using commands on textareas rather than contenteditable divs, not about changing the action of the command.

Comment: I don't think you can do this without a *substantial* amount of work that will probably require a great deal of cross-browser testing. I've tried a few things to try to make the browser mark an edit point so Undo does what you want, but not had any luck at all. I'm sure there's a way, but I bet (again) it's complicated and browser-sensitive.

Comment: Thank you for answers! But i change div tag to input tag and this problem disappeared :)

Answer (score -1):

In `doUndo()` instead of calling `execCommand` you could just remove the last character from the div, if it is not empty.

E.g.

```
function doUNDO() {
    var mainDIV = document.getElementById('mainDiv') 
    mainDIV.innerHTML = mainDIV.innerHTML.substr(0, mainDIV.innerHTML.length - 1);
```

}

Comment: The last character typed is not necessarily -- indeed, *frequently* not -- the last character in the div. Further, setting the div's `innerHTML` will probably screw up the position of the insertion point.

Comment: This logic doesn't help me, because my div tag can contains another tag on last position.