# Maintain undo functionality with createRange()

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable, undo-redo, rangy

I'm working on a Markdown text editor using a contenteditable and [Rangy](https://code.google.com/p/rangy/) to easily add links and images. The problem is that `rangy.createRange();`, an important function in the Rangy library, cancels the ability to undo an action (text added in the contenteditable in my case).

I have browsed the Web to find a solution and I have found [UndoManager](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/undomanager/raw-file/tip/undomanager.html), but I cannot find information about how to use it and if it has been added in Chrome (I'm working on a Chrome Packaged App so I don't care if Safari does not support it).

If somebody knows something about this piece of HTML5 it would be amazing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `createRange()` shouldn't affect the undo stack except in IE <= 8 (and compatibility modes in later versions). Do you need to support IE <= 8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2858919/javascript-undomanager-browser-support) , none of the current browsers support the UndoManager spec. You can test that in your browser by trying to access `document.undoManager` which `undefined` in Chrome